# Backbone.js and require.js tutorial misunderstanding

Tags: function, backbone.js, requirejs

I am following [this](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/4.html) backbone tutorial and [this](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/) require.js tutorial. I am trying to combine them.

When create an ItemListView, then I get an error

```
TypeError: singleItemView is not a function
   model: item
```

My code:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  // Pull in the Collection module from above
  'collections/projects',
  'collections/item',
  'models/projects'

], function($, _, Backbone, projectsCollection, singleItemView, itemViewModel){
  var projectListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),

....
....

    appendItem: function(item){
      var itemView = singleItemView({
        model: item
      });
      $('ul', this.el).append(itemView.render().el);
    }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: don't see any return in your code

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is just:

```
var itemView = new singleItemView({
    model: item
});
```

I'm not sure what singleItemView is. `collections/item` hints at it being a collection while the name singleItemView hints that it is a view. Whatever it is, it looks like it is a module with a "class" definition and I'm betting all you need to do is instantiate it.